# How to refer to a range with two variables

Tags: vba, variables, range

I'm putting together a report and can't figure out the syntax for referring to a range with two variable rows. This is what I currently have.

```
.Cells(mrow, 4).Value = Application.Sum(Range("D3:D" & brow - 1))
```

brow is a variable row that I've defined earlier in the code.

Instead of referring to D3:d(brow), how can I refer to D(arow):D(brow) in this range? I can't figure out where to place the quotes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Cells(mrow, 4).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("D" & arow & ":D" & brow - 1))
```

Or

```
.Cells(mrow, 4).Value = Application.Sum(,Range(.Cells(arow,4),.Cells(brow-1,4)))
```